# return; only with no return value

Tags: c++

What does it mean when someone codes:

```
 template <class T>
 void binaryTree<T>::in_order(Node <T>* node, void (*fun)(T&))
{
    if (node == NULL)   
            return;     //<-- what does this mean here

    inorder(node->left, fun);   //<-- how does this continue here
    f(node->data);
    inorder(node->right,fun);
}
```

The question is how do you have a return; without returning anything.  what does this do?
**Note, I have edited the code above for clarity.

Comment: I have edited the code to make the question more clear

Comment: It scared me when I scrolled up after answering the question. The whole snippet was changed :-)

Comment: yes my bad for putting crap code to begin with.

Comment: @user2884789 But you should have left your original sample. Now all the references in the answers are pretty useless :(

Answer (score 1):

It means that `foo(y)` is not executed when `x == 1`, you `return` from the function.

The code continues when `x != 1`, if you indent your code and put brackets in the `if` it'll be clearer:

```
void foo(int x, int y) { 
   if(x == 1) {
      return;    //return from the function, don't proceed to foo(y)
   }
   foo(y);   
}
```

> A return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list
>   can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a
>   function with the return type void.

See [this code](http://ideone.com/U1Hanz) on Ideone.

Comment: @Ashokkuttuva I didn't say it'll execute, I said it'll execute if `x` is **not** 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you format it better it might be easier to see:

```
void foo (int x, int y)
{ 
    if (x == 1)
        return;
    foo (y);
}
```

It simply returns **if** the variable `x` is equal to `1`. If `x` is **not** equal to `1` then the code skips to the recursive call to `foo` (and I really hope the real code is not like that, because you're calling `foo` with one argument when it wants two).

Answer (score 1):

it means if x == 1 then the function return without executing foo(y) function, if x != 1 , then the foo(y) function executes.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a function.

`foo` takes 2 parameters. Both parameters are `integer`. The parameters are named `x` and `y`.

The body of the function tests whether the value stored in the `x` variable is equal to 1.
If the value stored in `x` equals 1, then the function will return (exit).
If the value stored in `x` isn't equal to 1, then the function calls `foo(int x)`.

The `foo` called inside the function may be different to the `foo` function that you have supplied the code for (because it has a different interface/prototype).

What is the body of the second `foo` (the one that takes a single parameter)? It is possible that the prototype of `foo` specifies a default value for the parameters x & y (if this is the case then this may be the only `foo` function.

Comment: You can't really tell that `foo(y)` calls a different function as long we do not see it's declaration (think of parameter defaults)!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the confusing indentation, the `return` is inside the conditional statement.

The following is a slightly less confusing way to write that code:

```
if (x == 1)
   return;
foo (y);
```

Being inside the conditional statement, `return` is only executed if `x == 1`. In all cases, `foo(y)` is called.

Comment: foo(y) will not be called any more since it has only one arg instead of two.

Comment: @Ashokkuttuva That's bullshit, depends on declaration(s) which we don't see in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to see the `return` at last of the code, you can rewrite the code as::

```
void foo( int x, int y )
{
    if( x != 1 )
    {
        foo( y ) ;
    }
    else /* You can keep it to understand better visually. 
            Even if you don't keep it, the code would do the same */
    {
        return ; 
        /* returns the control to the caller code. 
           Make sure you understand that, it just returns the control but 
           without any value i.e., returning void. */
    }
}
```

EDIT:: `return` just returns the control to the caller. If you want to return  the control with some value, you would `return variable_name` and if you don't want to return anything, just `return`.

Real-Life Example::
Assume you have been asked to buy some soaps for bath. Now, if soaps are available at the store, you would come back and return me the soaps and caller will go to bath. This is you are returning back to the caller with some value. But suppose, if the store is out of soaps, then you would just simply return back to me and I will go to bath without any soap. This is you are returning back to the caller but without a value. In both the cases, you would return to the caller cuz the caller is waiting to proceed further with bathing only on your return.

Answer (score 0):

When a function return type is `void`, You can return from the function by writing `return` only. no need to give any value after `return`. 
If return type would have been `int` or `char` etc. then it is compulsory to give a value after `return`.